# UML - Help drawing crafting system

Tags: uml

I have drawn usecase, activity and class diagrams for "Crafting System" for my game.

I am bit confident in activity and use case diagrams but I doubt in class diagrams. Do you find any mistakes in it? or suggest any improvements?

[image: Crafting System - UML2 diagrams Usecase, Activity and Class diagrams]

Crafting Mechanic:

Crafter could be either an NPC or building thorough which player interacts to craft. Upon clicking on the crafter a window will be opened.

Comment: The question isn't really programming related; it's more programming process than actual programming.

Comment: then what is UML for here? why there is a UML tag created?

Comment: Because many of these questions deal with the implementation of UMLs through programming, not the creation and editing of UML's like you're asking about.

Comment: I found this in FAQ 

    a software algorithm
    software tools commonly used by programmers
    practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession
So what does it mean? Anyway I have flagged for moderation lets see what happens

Comment: Your not asking about a software development tool (the actual UML software) but instead the process of creating UMLs. Let's see what happens.

Comment: oh I just realized UML tools are not used for software development but for to cooking recipes.

Comment: Anyone with the least bit of intelligence would realize you aren't asking about a software development tool, you are asking about an organization process. A question about a software development tool would be "How do I do this using this UML software?" Not whats wrong with my UML.

Your question is also unique to you. Its not asking about a general problem but instead a specific problem only applying to YOU. You aren't asking about programming itself, but instead a problem only relevant  to you. Problems with YOUR UML aren't going to help others out. By the way, nice reputation.

Comment: But it needs little bit more intelligence to understand that UML itself is a tool used in software designs. I agree if you say "Your question is also unique to you". But I have asked this question because this is my first diagram and I might have made very silly mistakes and I was expecting suggestions/improvements/corrections.

Comment: UML is a organization tool, not a software program used by programmers. Examples of UML software would be something like Gliffy. Asking about the software would be valid, but your not. Secondly, it doesnt matter if it's your first UML. If it is only applicable to you then it shouldn't be posted here. Since you like the FAQ so much, how about you read up on it? I would suggest moving this topic to Programmers, a site specifically made for things like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm. If we look at a crafting process in a very abstract way this may work. What I'd miss here are the directional (aka one-sided) dependencies in the class diagram; for example the crafting process may not now anything about the crafter. Same goes for the items.

In a more detailed look at this you will have to split up some compound classes. For example, the crafting process is likely going to be split into at least two classes, if not even more. The reason behind this is that you'd like to keep the data ("recipe") split from the actual process. This will not only make things easier with the actual implementation, but also gives you a means to provide actual recipe items to the player.

Which brings me to another point: If you have some kind of item tree, your ConsumableItem and CraftableItem are more like interfaces with the same parent. Infact, I honestly fail to see why you would make any difference between these two, because you may have mixed up classes and roles here (which are described differently in UML).